# Is it posssible to batch different inserts/IDbCommands together with Nhibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Example 1, the following insert results in 2 batches regardless of your configuration:

```
INSERT INTO <b>entitytable1</b> (someInt) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO <b>entitytable2</b> (someInt) VALUES (3)
-- Notice tables are <b>different</b>
-- Results in <b>2</b> round trips to the db
-- C# code that can generate such statements:
   session.Save(typeof(entitytable<b>1</b>), new entitytable<b>1</b>{someInt = 1})
   session.Save(typeof(entitytable<b>2</b>), new entitytable<b>2</b>{someInt = 3})
   transction.Commit();
```

However, in example 2, below, the inserts result in 1 batch:

```
INSERT INTO <b>entitytable1</b> (someInt) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO <b>entitytable1</b> (someInt) VALUES (3)
-- Notice tables are the <b>same</b>
-- Results in <b>1</b> round trip to the db
-- C# code that can generate such statements:
   session.Save(typeof(entitytable<b>1</b>), new entitytable<b>1</b>{someInt = 1})
   session.Save(typeof(entitytable<b>1</b>), new entitytable<b>1</b>{someInt = 3})
   transction.Commit();
```

Is it possible to get example 1 to work as 2, that is, to send different inserts batched together to the db (e.g. 1 roundtrip)?

Batching definition, for the few: To send multiple statements/inserts grouped together, up to Ado_Batch_size, to the database in one round trip.

The sql shown above is generated by Nhibernate of course!. It is what you would see on NHProfiler.

Version: Nhibernate 3.2

Comment: maybe i'm missing something, but what is the difference in 1 and 2?  looks identical.

Comment: @nathangonzalez the tables names. They are 2 completely different inserts.

Comment: i see now.  what does "batch" mean to you?  and how does this relate to nhibernate?  that's just sql.

Comment: @nathangonzalez See my updated question. I guess I assumed too much. You know Nhibernate has built-in IDbCommand batchers don't you? They seem to not be able to batch different insert-IDbCommands together.

Comment: Why are you issuing SQL rather than using instances of your entity classes? This appears to be defeating the point of an O/RM.

Comment: @TrueWill See my updated question. The sql is generated by nhibernate on session.flush/transaction.commit. No hand written sql here.

Comment: Please remember that we cannot read your mind. You might consider posting the C# code as well. Statements like "of course", "for the few", and "don't you?" could be taken as condescending. Remember, most of the people answering questions are volunteers.

Comment: @TrueWill Acknowledged. Also, please, see my updated question.

Comment: @Newbie, when formatting code on SO, don't use the <pre> tag.  Just indent with four spaces.

Comment: @Inuyasha how do I bold some text if I only use four spaces? Only with pre I've been able to do this. With you change, now all the code is off. see the <b> tags.

Comment: @Inuyasha - actually the pre was my doing. There were some initial subtleties that caused misunderstandings, and I wanted to emphasize those with b tags as the OP mentioned. Also note that syntax highlighting adds little benefit when the code is mixed SQL, comments, and C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [nHibernate batch insert doesn't work with associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181558/nhibernate-batch-insert-doesnt-work-with-associations) (which the original poster already found), it appears that this is not supported by the current version of NHibernate.

The article [Profiling NHibernate Batching](http://www.codinginstinct.com/2009/08/profiling-nhibernate-batching.html) seems to confirm this, and suggests using [stateless sessions](http://davybrion.com/blog/2008/10/bulk-data-operations-with-nhibernates-stateless-sessions/) (which unfortunately ignore associations).

Alternately, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4167564/161457) suggests using HQL.

Caveat: I am not an NHibernate user. Be sure to check the actual behavior with NHProfiler.